# Should a client check for persisted item existence before modifying it?

Tags: java, mvc, rest, exceptions

I'm developing a MVC Web application with a REST interface.

The REST controller performs actions on persisted items through a service class, which translates exceptions coming from the persistence layer.

When a request involves an item that not exists in the database, I would like to return 404 code, but actually this is not possible due to the exception translation operated by the service, that prevents the controller from knowing the reason of the problem.

Should the service class return a particular exception *only* for this case? Conversely, should the controller check for item existence before any action?

Comment: "but actually this is not possible due to the exception translation" - can you elaborate on why this isn't possible ? Most web frameworks allow you to respond 404 in some way (raise a specific exception, controller returns a certain value, etc.) Which exception comes out of the service class is kind of irrelevant to this, you can always catch it, right ?

Comment: Right. 
Edited with more details.

Comment: Shouldn't the controller be able to know what exception was thrown? This seems like a bad design.

Comment: I think that bad design would be letting an exception thrown in the persistence layer reach the controller without adding relevant context (that could come from the service), hence the exception translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Service layer can translate exception received from lower layers to avoid coupling between the controller and the persistence layer. But in doing that translation, the Service layer should *not* throw away/obscure information that could be relevant for dealing with the reported error.

So, the Service layer should in general have a one-to-one mapping between persistence exceptions and the exceptions they get translated into. You should only deviate from that if the persistence layer, for legacy reasons, throws two different exceptions for one and the same problem.

Comment: Seems reasonable. But would be difficult to map _all_ the exception that the persistence layer could throw. I think I'll go mapping only exceptions that one expects a service to throw (object not found, already exists, etc.) and translate anything else into a more generic "service exception".

Comment: @aleric: Be careful that you don't lump stuff together that needs different treatment when handling the error. Otherwise, that is a reasonable way to start.

Answer (score 0):

In most applications, the Service would retrieve the object it needs through the data access layer (effectively loading it in memory) before it can modify it and save it back.

If the object doesn't exist, the data access object would probably return null. I would maybe not raise an exception at that point but at least return a specific error case value. The Controller would get it and respond with a 404.

Comment: The data access layer throws an unchecked exception (I'm using Spring's JdbcTemplate), that, as I said, gets translated by the service.
I would not consider returning error values anyway, since I'm programming in Java.

Comment: What prevents you from translating that exception too ? Do you have control over what happens in the service at all ? And I'm not talking about your C-like integer error codes but a real [special case error object].(http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html)

Comment: Plus, a Data Access Object or Repository should probably be here to translate from the world of low-level data access stuff to the world of your business objects. In the case of the database throwing because the data was not found, it should probably catch it and return null.

Comment: That's the point. Translating that exception too, will cause the controller to miss the reason of the exception, losing the chance to know that the object is not found.

Comment: Thanks for citing the special case object (try to remove the dot between parenthesis to get the link working).

Comment: You might want to clarify in the Q what "translating" means in your context. Something seems to prevent you from handling a JDBC exception cleanly, but I have no idea what or why...